# The most efficient way to subset elements by indexes from larger dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and I would like to subset some elements from this dataframe by indexes. And these indexes are stored in another dataframe. For instance:

The original dataframe:

```
 1 4 2 5 8 2
 2 8 2 3 5 0
 0 2 2 4 1 3
 1 8 3 2 2 1
```

And the dataframe of indexes:

```
 2 3
 2 6
 3 3
 4 5
```

So the result dataframe of subseting is:

```
 2
 0
 2
 2
```

What is the most efficient way to subset a large dataframe by indexes? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Search here for `[r] matrix indexing` - try  `orig[as.matrix(index)]`

Comment: @SymbolixAU Thank you for your correction.

Answer (score 0):

If the original dataframe is `df`, and the index are stored in a matrix `ind`, just try:

```
df[ind]
```

Remember that the `ncol(ind)`must be the same as `length(dim(df))` or you will get an error.